# Using Django without templates?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

Forgive my knowledge on django, although I was briefly talking with a developer from Google whom I had met and he stated something confusing to me.

He mentioned something that I hadn't really gotten a chance to ask him more about.
He told me to be careful with django templates because in terms of scale, they can cause problems and almost always need to be re-written. Rather he mentioned something like using a 'full stack' with django.

I think back, and I don't exactly follow what he means by that. Is their a way to use Django without templates? Is it better ? Why or why not?

Answer (score 2):

If you are making a web app, I'd say you need templates. Any other solution would be a mess.

However, django templates have been known to not scale well because rendering them is relatively slow compared to other solutions like jinja2. There are several apps that integrate jinja2 into django. There's also been a lot of discussion on integrating jinja2 into django core itself someday in the future.

So if you are scaling up big time, you may to investigate performance and optimize template rendering. There are some big sites using django like Pinterest, Instagram, and bitbucket, so they must have figured out a way. But for the most part, django template performance is just fine.

Comment: To add to this comment, if you look at page load time as a whole the actual time spent rendering a page is pretty small compared to network latency, database access etc. Until your site has scaled to the point where this is really a problem and other areas that provide a greater improvement have already been optimised stick with the default, otherwise you will spend a lot of time trying to solve a problem that has a fairly low net benefit.

Comment: Thank you very much. I figured worrying about this early on wouldn't be necessary. I appreciate the comments guys.

Comment: Even django template is slow, how could it affairs scalibity?  And according to an interview to Instagram's CTO, django's default template performance is good enough.